# Possible to automatically open an outlook app?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365, office-2013, office365-apps

I've built an Outlook app (for Office 2013) that displays information about the person I'm writing an email to.  However, it seems that every time I compose a new message, I have to click on apps and then click on my app to actually enable the functionality.  Is there a way to force Outlook to automatically trigger my app as soon as I start composing a message?  Or do I have to write a more traditional addin (instead of this new javascript plugin style) to get that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write an Outlook addin. It will be loaded  every time Outlook runs. You will then be able to listen to various Outlook events and/or provide your custom ribbon UI.

Start at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx

Comment: And I'm guessing there's no way to make something that would work like this for Outlook Web Access except via a chrome extension or something similar to that?

Comment: You can create a Mail app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161135(v=office.15).aspx . The API is very limited; at least in the current version.

Comment: Yeah, mail app is what I've built so far, it just requires them to open it every time.  Guess it's the best I can do.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can usePinnable Taskpane in Outlook 2016 but only support in outlook 2016 even not in OWA